# std::regex to find word within brackets inside a string, then replace it (and the brackets)

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, stl

Having some trouble with this one. I'm using std::regex for the first time and the syntax is a little unintuitive to me.

I've got strings with stuff like **[VARIABLE]** and sometimes **[VARIABLEA]** \ **[VARIABLEB]**.

Let's say for example I want to replace **[VARIABLEA]** with Windows and **[VARIABLEB]** with System32, so the result would be **Windows\System32**.

What do you think the best regex would be for finding these matches? What do you think the best method for replacing them is?

I basically have been streaming into a Stringstream for my replacements (When I find a match i put in the the new value, when I don't i put in the original key, for all else I just stream in). But I wasn't sure if std::regex maybe provided some better option for this.

Here's the regex I've been trying: `std::regex("\\\\*\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\\\*");`

I'm on a fairly tight schedule and just been banging my head on the desk for too long with this one. I know it's probably very simple, but I am a slow learned. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

EDIT:

Also, I tried to simplify this a little for the post, but just to be real clear, I'm using unicode strings so it's really `std::wregex(L"\\\\*\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\\\*");`. So I don't know if I can pop the R for raw literals on there.

Comment: You should use _raw string literals_ for regular expressions: `R"(\[[^]]\])"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regex of something like:

`@"^\[VARIABLEA\]$"`which will get you a match when you parse through your strings.

You can also use the .split() or Regex.split() method to split your strings into arrays on a delimiter
SEE: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Then just replace where you find your match.

Comment: Not sure why, but it didn't post the '\' in front of the '[' and ']' for the Regex.

Comment: Fixed it for you, but this isn't obj-c why is there an @ in front of your string

Comment: And you have do quite the `\`, too and or use raw strings: `R"(^\[VARIABLEA\]$)"`.